# How to close popup when youtube video is playing on esc button button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[Click me to see the demo](http://jsbin.com/vudiba/6/edit?html,css,js,output)

When video is not playing then Esc button pressed the popup closes but it does not work when video is playing.

Comment: Are you sure it works when the video is not playing?

Answer (score 0):

In your demo, ensure the iframe containing the video is cleared when the layer is hidden. Change your hide function to this:

```
function popup(){
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-bann')[0];
    img.querySelector('iframe').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mQLTWvXbXM";
    document.getElementsByClassName('pop')[0].style.display="block";
}

function hide(e) {
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-bann')[0];
    if (img.contains(e.target)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    img.querySelector('iframe').src = "about:blank";
    document.getElementsByClassName('pop')[0].style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I think what I am trying to achieve cannot be done because iframe takes from different domain.

Comment: I see. However I used this in your demo fiddle and the close button removed the video and hid the overlaying container, which is what I thought you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I needed that also I have tried its working, but this post was to stop video when I press esc button while playing video.

Comment: I mean: In your fiddle, using the above hide function, when the video is playing and I press the the close button, the video stops.

Comment: I added the video URL in the popup function, so that the video loads again when popup is reopened. Tested in Chrome, FF and IE11.